# Mysterious margin between divs

Tags: html, css

I cannot figure out why there is a space between the blue and the red divs here:

[image: Screenshot.]

I’ve messed around with the `padding` and `margin`s for a while now but nothing seems to work.

```css
#header {
  background-color: green;
}

#title {
  background-color: blue;
  font-size: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

#strip {
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 40%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
}

.menu-button {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="title">
    <p>Title</p>
  </div>
  <div id="strip">
    <div class="menu-button">
      <p>menu</p>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-button">
      <p>menu</p>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-button">
      <p>menu</p>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-button">
      <p>menu</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The red div is a child of the green div, so obviously it's going to look like that.

Comment: The `<p>` element takes the margin-bottom property from the default browser's style. If you set its margin to zero it will solve the problem.

Comment: What is the expected result? Please use the [developer tools](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and inspect each element. Look at their box models. The first `<p>` has a default margin which causes the red `<div>`s to be pushed down.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you. I didn't know that the <p> element had its own margin property I needed to worry about.

Comment: You should use `class` instead of `id` for CSS styling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

body and p have default margin values.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

#header {
    background-color: green;
}

#title {
    background-color: blue;
    font-size: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

#title>p {
    margin: 0;
}

#strip {
    background-color: red;
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 40%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
}

.menu-button {
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.menu-button>p {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <div id="title">
        <p>Title</p>
    </div>
    <div id="strip">
        <div class="menu-button">
            <p>menu</p>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-button">
            <p>menu</p>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-button">
            <p>menu</p>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-button">
            <p>menu</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should consider resetting all margin and padding at the start of all your css to avoid unwanted margins like this.

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```